# Run Spring MVC project on Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, raspberry-pi, beagleboneblack

Hi I am a newbie with Spring MVC and I have a little problem.

I can't deploy this project on a Tomcat server. https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

I can run the project by running it as an application. And you see everything starting in the console, with a spring boot. And if I go to http://localhost:8080/ I see the right page.

I think this is deployed on an internal Tomcat server, but what do I have to do if I want to deploy it on another server, raspberry pi or a BeagleBone with a Tomcat server installed on it ?

I tried to use the WAR file to deploy on an external tomcat server but that doesn't work because i think its because this project doesn't use a WEB-INF folder and also has no web.xml file.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of tomcat are you deploying it to? `web.xml` isn't necessary  because web applications can be configured with annotations, but it requires at least Tomcat 7 for it to work.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 8.0.21, thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: What errors do you see in Tomcat logs when you deploy the war?

Comment: I see in the log text file tomcat8-stdout.2015-03-31

31-Mar-2015 11:54:42.445 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\gs-securing-web-complete.war
31-Mar-2015 11:54:42.915 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\gs-securing-web-complete.war has finished in 470 ms

Comment: Is there a way to see a live log of Tomcat or where it is best to see errors in Tomcat  ?